# play audio file dynamically with naudio

Tags: c#, multithreading, audio, naudio

I am working with a project which will take input from another system. The input can be  signals in of form parameters (integer values). My application will play different sounds  dynamically base on inputs values. For example, when program get parameter value 2 it should play 2 files with sounds A and B parallel. I can play sounds simultaneous with naudio but so far they are hard coded. And I need to play sounds from a folder which can have N sounds. Is possible that some way to select and play only files that contain A and B sounds dynamically if I get value 2? but if I get parameter value 3 then situation will be different, for instance I would like to play a sound C. Please suggest me any piece of code or ideas that help me to write an algorithm that does some like this?

I really appreciate your valuable guidance

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need a mixer object to combine the wave data from the source files and produce an output waveform that can be fed to your `WaveOut` instance.  There a few mixers in NAudio:  `MixingWaveProvider16`, `WaveMixerStream32` and `MixingSampleProvider` for instance.  These will help you combine the wave data from the source files into a composite waveform that you can play.

The other option is to implement an `IWaveProvider` that will handle multiple inputs and mix down to a single output stream in the desired format.  In this scenario you would have an output buffer and a list of input streams/buffers to be mixed.  When more data is required in the output buffer it would mix the source data on-the-fly, possibly using one of the provided mixer classes.

Personally I'd suggest writing your own mixer.  It's good exercise and will give you a better understanding of what's going on.

If you're mixing 16-bit streams you need to use a 32-bit buffer to mix into, as two 16-bit inputs added together can produce values greater than a 16-bit value can hold.  The more inputs you have, the greater the likelihood of going outside the valid range.  There are a few ways to deal with this.  Just clamping the output between `Int16.MinValue` and `Int16.MaxValue` is a quick-and-nasty approach that may work for you.  As tempting as it may seem, I would suggest you NOT try to average samples... it reduces the overall dynamic range of the output too much.